# Mocking a protected method always returning true

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, moq

I have the following protected method in my base class:

```
protected bool ExecuteInteraction(string identifier,
    Action<object> interactionFinished, params object[] args)
{
    Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(identifier));
    Contract.Requires(interactionFinished != null);

    bool result = false;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(identifier) && (interactionFinished != null))
    {
        // Find the matching interaction behavior.
        IInteractionBehavior interactionBehavior =
            InteractionBehaviorCollection.Instance.Get(identifier);

        if (interactionBehavior != null)
        {
            try
            {
                interactionBehavior.Execute(interactionFinished, args);
                result = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(
                "InteractionBehavior with identifier [{0}] is unknown",
                identifier));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

It's basically from this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/708346/Dialogs-the-MVVM-Way ...

This method is used in my derived class like that:

```
protected override void Delete()
{
    try
    {
        if (PrimaryModel.Id != 0 && PrimaryModel.AddressId != 0)
        {
            ExecuteInteraction("DeleteConfirmation", (result) =>
            {
                MessageBoxResult messageBoxResult = (MessageBoxResult)result;

                if (messageBoxResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                {
                    //Do something ...
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Message = exc.Message;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work in my unit test because I don't simulate that messageBoxResult is MessageBoxResult.Yes. This is the reason why I'd like my protected method to always returning true in the unit test. How can I do that (with moq)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to interface your `MessageBox` actions so that you can provide a `MockMessageBox` when unit testing that always returns `MessageBoxResult.Yes`. So, in your code, *don't* reference any `MessageBox`es directly. Create a `WindowManager` or `MessageBoxService` class that you call instead, kind of like a proxy message box.

For example, try something like this:

```
public string ShowMessageBox(string message, string title, string buttons, string icon)
{
    MessageBoxButton messageBoxButtons;
    switch (buttons.ToLower())
    {
        case "ok": messageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButton.OK; break;
        case "okcancel": messageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel; break;
        case "yesno": messageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButton.YesNo; break;
        case "yesnocancel": messageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel; break;
        default: messageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel; break;
    }
    MessageBoxImage messageBoxImage;
    switch (icon.ToLower())
    {
        case "asterisk": messageBoxImage = MessageBoxImage.Asterisk; break;
        case "error": messageBoxImage = MessageBoxImage.Error; break;
        case "exclamation": messageBoxImage = MessageBoxImage.Exclamation; break;
        case "hand": messageBoxImage = MessageBoxImage.Hand; break;
        case "information": messageBoxImage = MessageBoxImage.Information; break;
        case "none": messageBoxImage = MessageBoxImage.None; break;
        case "question": messageBoxImage = MessageBoxImage.Question; break;
        case "stop": messageBoxImage = MessageBoxImage.Stop; break;
        case "warning": messageBoxImage = MessageBoxImage.Warning; break;
        default: messageBoxImage = MessageBoxImage.Stop; break;
    }
    return MessageBox.Show(message, title, messageBoxButtons, messageBoxImage).ToString();
}
```

This would be called like this:

```
string result = WindowManager.ShowMessageBox(message, title, "OkCancel", "Question");
```

Note how there are no direct relations to any UI dlls... all properties are string based. Now you need to interface the class that this method is in (`WindowManager`). So now we have an `IWindowManager` that forces us to write a `ShowMessageBox` method in all implementing classes.

Now we implement this interface in a `MockWindowManager` class:

```
public string ShowMessageBox(string message, string title, string buttons, string icon)
{
    switch (buttons)
    {
        case "Ok":
        case "OkCancel": return "OK";
        case "YesNo":
        case "YesNoCancel": return "Yes";
        default: return "OK";
    }
}
```

When running the application, we use the `WindowManager` class and when testing, we use the `MockWindowManager` class. This can be achieved in a number of ways, but the easiest is to pass an `IWindowManager` into the view model constructor:

```
public YourViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager)
{
    this.windowManager = windowManager;
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right and I get the idea. Mocking an interface isn't the problem. What confuses me is ExecuteInteraction("DeleteConfirmation", (result) => { ... I don't know what to do that my result is always true. I'm not sure what exactly to mock in my code (I don't have any ShowMessageBox-logic or something).

Comment: That's your problem... you need to remove all references to `MessageBox` and `MessageBoxResult`, etc. from your code and replace them with calls to a new `WindowManager` or similar class. Then that code will run the same when you test or when you are live. The difference is that when you are testing, you use the `MockWindowManager` class which automatically returns `Yes` instead of waiting for a user to click something.

Comment: I followed your recommandations and it's working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest you to follow the concept explained by @Sheridan; but if you want to go your way, here is the solution how to mock a protected method:

```
Mock<YourBaseClass> baseClassMock = new Mock<YourBaseClass>();
baseClassMock.Protected().Setup<bool>(
    "ExecuteInteraction", 
     ItExpr.IsAny<string>(),
     ItExpr.IsAny<Action<object>>(),
     ItExpr.IsAny<object[]>())
.Returns(true);
```